# Unable to do two way binding in Mat-Datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, angular6

here is my code below. I'm using mat-datepicker and I make it year picker by doing customization in it. The issue is when I implement `name="control" #control="ngModel" [(ngModel)]=""` so it throws me error in my console, But when I remove `name="control" #control="ngModel" [(ngModel)]=""` from control so it's working fine.

```
    <input class="form-control" name="FDConversationDateYear" #FDConversationDateYear="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="objCompanyFinancialDetails.FDConversationDateYear" [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Month and Year" [formControl]="date" required>

<mat-datepicker-toggle class="datepicker-toggler" matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                    <mat-datepicker #dp
                                                    startView="multi-year"
                                                    (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event, dp)"
                                                    panelClass="example-month-picker">
                                    </mat-datepicker>
```

Here is component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker emulating a Year and month picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-views-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-views-selection-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-views-selection-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
  }
}
```

and here is my console errors

[image: Here is my console error image]

Comment: Please import the FormsModule or the ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms and try.

Comment: It's already imported.

Comment: Why do you even want to bind it? just for two way binding? However, Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with
reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed
in Angular v7.

Comment: So how can I bind this control, or send it's value to my model class?

Comment: You have date as a form control in your component. So the date you select is bound to that. Just put {{date}} in your html somewhere and see it after you select a date

Comment: Is there any other way to make year picker of mat-datepicker?

Comment: I tried yesterday but could not succeed. There is an open PR for the same I think.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `formControl` attribute as you are using Template Driven Forms:

HTML Code:

```
<input class="form-control" name="FDConversationDateYear" #FDConversationDateYear="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="date" [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Month and Year" required>
<mat-datepicker-toggle class="datepicker-toggler" matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dp startView="multi-year" (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event, dp)" panelClass="example-month-picker">
</mat-datepicker>
```

TS Code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Datepicker selected value */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  date = new Date();
}
```

<kbd>[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8hqyn-52t76k)</kbd>

Comment: How can I make this year picker only?\

Comment: only year is not possible, Month and year is possible!

Comment: But here is we also need to implement formControl.

Comment: reason behind this?

Comment: because we have to customize that control.. If you have any other other solution so kindly share with me .. Thanks

Comment: Then you can use reactive form with the help of patch method